# Material UI responsive grid direction column

Tags: material-ui

Is there some way to make responsive grid's rows with direction column?
For example **md=6** *columns*, **sm=12** *columns* etc.

Comment: Everything is possible if you edit the source code. But otherwise no, I don't think so. Which makes sense, since it's the device width that should be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm using *useMediaQueries* and *Breakpoints* to check condition true or false, then render elements...